# Div align changes with putting class after id

Tags: php, css

I am really facing a strange problem. Here is the following code and example picture of the code

HTML

```
<div id="showCatagory_<?php echo $row['catagory_id']; ?>" class="left"  style="display:block">
<?php echo $value; ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left { float:left }
```

When I am using this `<div id="showCatagory_<?php echo $row['catagory_id']; ?>" class="left"  style="display:block">` then I am getting the picture following which is wrong

[image]

And if I use `<div class="left" id="showCatagory_<?php echo $row['catagory_id']; ?>"  style="display:block">` then I am getting right alignment which is on the following picture

here I am putting `class="left"` after id to make it right. Can anyone tell me why

[image]

Can anyone please tell me why

```
<div class="left" id="showCatagory_<?php echo $row['catagory_id']; ?>" class="left"  style="display:block">
```

is being different than

```
<div id="showCatagory_<?php echo $row['catagory_id']; ?>" class="left" style="display:block">
```

Comment: Can you show a demo of this issue? Its hard to judge the culprit from the code provided.

Comment: Are you asking what `float: left;` does or is the last PHP block supposed to  have `class="left"`?

Comment: On the bottom part you are declaring class twice, why?

Comment: I assume in the last two lines of code, you have typos -- the first has two "class"es, and the second has no "class". Are you sure there aren't typos in your script?

Comment: I am unable to provide any live demo as it is coming from Ajax and I don't have any live site to put all the files and show there.

My question is why putting class before id is making the result different. Is it bug of php or something

Comment: is there any css associated with the id? could be a conflict - other than that i think float:left; & display: block; is a bit strange because one implies it will take the full width & the other implies it will collapse to content - you can't have it both ways - so perhaps you should say display: inline-block;

Comment: @Jhilom, You any create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net and show the issue

Comment: No RiquezJP. There is no CSS attached with this ID. And Starx. How can I load 10 pages on jsfiddle.net. And 4 pages are on ajax...

Answer (score 1):

There are still a bunch of typos in the question, if you look closely... but I get what you mean... you are asking why the position of the class attribute is affecting the outcome.

Almost certainly there's an extraneous quotemark or similar in there that is breaking up your html.  What does `$row[category_id']` contain? On the off-chance there's a quote mark in there, you could try `str_replace('"', '', $row[category_id]);`

Comment: @Starx -- it didnt when he posted it!

Comment: Jhong was write. I missed typing quotes at the time of posting Question then I edited it. But in real code I have quotes

Answer (score 1):

As long as your values are sanitised; the only thing that would cause this is your PHP throwing an error inside the inline statement that ruins the tag markup.

```
<tag foo="bar" bar="<?php echo foo(); ?>"></tag>
```

In this example, if the `foo()` function raised an error, and PHP inserted a big error report instead, the HTML would end up looking something like this:

```
<tag foo="bar" bar="Error Statement:
Error details...
  > Error echoes HTML markup characters.
Error trace information (line: 263)"></tag>
```

Any of the markup characters contained in the error would break the tag. So if `foo="bar"` was after the PHP error, it wouldn't belong to the tag since it was broken off by the error.

Answer (score 1):

I was stupid. I used the float:left but didn't use clear. And after used that I got the right display. Thanks Everyone